# InfoPath "The SOAP message cannot be parsed"

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I work on a simple list on a simple site/site collection/web app on a SharePoint 2010 test server which does not use SSL.

I then make a site collection backup and restord it onto our Production environment which have the same setup as the test server. The only difference is that it is set up to use SSL encryption and in particular for this web app.

When I want to customize the forms of the list using InfoPath I get a weird error message : "The SOAP message cannot be parsed".

[image: InfoPath error window]

This is when I click on the "Customize form" button in the ribbon which has the InfoPath icon:

[image: Customize Form button from the ribbon]

Does anybody have already encountered such problem?
I have seen many posts about this error but this is because of athe time out issue when the list contains a lot of items. In my case, it is empty.

Thanks,

Sébastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem was coming from the fact that InfoPath initially tried to connect using http to the SharePoint site. When the settings were changed to https, the IE cache still kept this setting and I had to remove it using the "Reset..." button located on the Advanced tab of the Internet options so that IE now opens up InfoPath using the right URL with https.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "The SOAP message cannot be parsed." while publishing a very complicated (list-based) InfoPath form in SharePoint Enterprise 2010. The issue only seemed to be effecting this form and not any others but would fail with either my personal account or the farm account.

After some experimenting with timing values within the InfoPath Service(s) we expanded the ExecutionTimeout in the Web.Config file within I.I.S. and that worked.

Comment: Do you have any additional details?

Comment: it is this timeout <httpRuntime maxRequestLength=”2097151″ executionTimeout=”3600″ />